# How to do Remote Development to one of multiple VS Code on one machine?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

On a remote server (running Ubuntu), I have two instances of VS Code. One instance of VS Code that is installed by `.deb` file from Microsoft website, this instance is used by multiple users, let's call this the global instance. The other one is a portable version of VS Code that I get from downloading `.tar.gz` file from Microsoft website. This portable instance is a custom version of mine to do my own development.

The global instance has the 'Remote-Development' extension pack installed so other machines can do Remote Development with it from their local machines. I also want to do Remote Development with the portable instance of mine. Is this possible? If so, how can I set it up?

Comment: I'm confused. though I haven't tried it myself, I can't see immediately why this would be difficult. which [step in the setup](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/vscode-server#_getting-started) are you stuck at?